# how can i take uitableview header behind status bar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, statusbar, uitableviewsectionheader

I have added two images, first one shows what i want and second one shows what is happening. I want uitableview header to go behind the status bar as shown in first image. deployment target is 9.2

[image]

and second one is

[image]

Comment: did you use autolayout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using [`Autolayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) so you can either constraint tableView's `.top` margin to its super view's `.top` or view controller's `topLayoutGuide` property so that the table view will start from `0`:

```
let toItem: Any = self.topLayoutGuide 
// You can change this to `self.view` to have the same effect. 

view.addConstraint(
  NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, 
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, 
    toItem: toItem, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0
  )
)
```

Here is how it looks in my simulator:

[image]

To have the table header start below the status bar, just use `layoutGuide`'s `.bottom` property instead of `.top`:

[image]

Here you can [download](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lpb1himnb5eegfi/AAB8hS3f66nzvfR081oarl7Ha?dl=0) the test project.

Comment: Great. I was adding .top to layoutGuide's rather than to SuperView

Comment: How can we do it in storyboard? XCode Version 11.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Warning from Xcode: 'topLayoutGuide' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor

So now you can do this to achieve the same effect.

```swift
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Note we use `.topAnchor` of safeAreaLayoutGuide here.